# AVRO serialization exception UTF8\String

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, avro

I have a kafka producer and consumer on different services, the consumer code was rolled out and worked fine then today I rolled out the producer side changes and get the serialization exception here on the consumer.  I use an confluent AVRO schema registry server, which had also been working fine until today.

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id 59
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.avro.util.Utf8 cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (org.apache.avro.util.Utf8 is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @77bd7fe7; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at com.mydev.ret.lib.avro.mark.put(Mark.java:132)
```

As part of this the schema has changed but that is not the first time this has happened, what might be significant is the we are after moving to avro 1.9.1 AND kafka-avro-serializer-6.0.0

Any ideas,  seeing the string and UTF issue makes me thing there might be an artifact mismatch across producer and consumer.

Comment: In the Avro maven plugin, you can configure which type of object strings become. Utf8, or java.lang.String... You might want to check what class is used in your compiled object

Comment: This is what I see in my compiled object:                                                                    case 0: orgId = (java.lang.String)value$; break;                          Does that mean its using String or UTF8?

Comment: This is in my maven avro plugin:  <stringType>String</stringType>

Comment: Okay, and that field was not changed in the newer producer code? If not, then I would imagine the consumer would continue to work. But I also remember following the Avro JIRA around some issues with Avro 1.9.x features and consuming 1.8.x serialized data (might be related to the issue you found as well). Even if the schema hasn't changed, then upgrading the consumer avro version as well might work.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error in Flink, when converted DataStream to Table. Search in internet suggested this question that is unanswered, however @mrmannione suggested in his comment to add

```
 <stringType>String</stringType>
```

and it resolved my issue, so i am leaving it here for others with example of usage in pom.xml

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>schema</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/schema</sourceDirectory>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/</outputDirectory>
                        <stringType>String</stringType>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```